# Images shrinks after multiple zoom

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, cgaffinetransformscale

i don't know what i am doing wrong. After multiple scale my image gets smaller ?!?
I initialize the variables as follows:
     TOTAL_SCALE = 1.0;
      MIN_SCALE = 1.0;
     MAX_SCALE = 3.0;

and this its my pinchrecognizermethod:

```
- (void)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchRecognizer
{

CGFloat scale = pinchRecognizer.scale;
if (TOTAL_SCALE + (scale - 1.0) > MAX_SCALE) {
    scale = (MAX_SCALE - TOTAL_SCALE) + 1.0;
    TOTAL_SCALE = MAX_SCALE;
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(imageView.transform, scale, scale);
}
else if(TOTAL_SCALE + (scale - 1.0) < MIN_SCALE){
    scale = (TOTAL_SCALE - MIN_SCALE) + 1.0;
    TOTAL_SCALE = MIN_SCALE;
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(imageView.transform, scale, scale);
}
else{
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(imageView.transform, scale, scale);
    TOTAL_SCALE += (scale - 1.0); 
}
pinchRecognizer.scale = 1.0;

}
```

Can anybody find my mistake?
Thank in advance!

Comment: I don't know how iOS does transformations, but this kind of behavior in other settings just means you need to initialize the current transformation to the identity before concatenating the scale operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what this line produces when `TOTALSCALE` is greater than `MAXSCALE`:

```
scale = (MAX_SCALE - TOTAL_SCALE) + 1.0;
```

And as a general guide you should be multiplying scales, not adding them.

Comment: But how can TOTAL_SCALE be greater than MAX_SCALE? as i am asking if (TOTAL_SCALE + (scale - 1.0) > MAX_SCALE)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the addition to multiplication as Mark Ransom suggested:

```
CGFloat scale = pinchRecognizer.scale;
if (TOTAL_SCALE*scale > MAX_SCALE) {
    scale = MAX_SCALE/TOTAL_SCALE;
    TOTAL_SCALE = MAX_SCALE;
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(imageView.transform, scale, scale);
}
else if(TOTAL_SCALE*scale < MIN_SCALE){
    scale = MIN_SCALE/TOTAL_SCALE;
    TOTAL_SCALE = MIN_SCALE;
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(imageView.transform, scale, scale);
}
else{
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(imageView.transform, scale, scale);
    TOTAL_SCALE *= scale; 
}
```